# how to find pipe and replace with @ into the bracket of string from pattern

Tags: javascript

Find Pipe into the `(fad(dfad) | dfasd |dada(dafs))` and replace with `@` from `jquery` pattern.

```
var str = 'da(dd) | dasd(dsa) | dad(asdf) (fad(dfad) | dfasd |dada(dafs)) | adfs(daf)'

str.replace(/([\|])/g,'@'); --- not working.
```

I want Output: da(dd) | dasd(dsa) | dad(asdf) (fad(dfad) @ dfasd @ dada(dafs)) | adfs(daf)

Please help me for find the result;

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. http://i.imgur.com/4JiCGk3.png

Comment: It works for me too. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17606289/5897779) is a quite extensive answer to what you want to do :)

Comment: I want output: da(dd) | dasd(dsa) | dad(asdf) (fad(dfad) @ dfasd @ dada(dafs)) | adfs(daf)

Comment: Will the parenthesis always follow that same pattern? If so I'll make a regex finding the section you want

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered a bit and put the following together which will have the effect you want. Assuming that the pattern of character types will remain the same.

```
str.replace(/(?:(\(\w*\([^|]*)(\|)([^|]*)(\|)(.*))/,'$1@$3@$5');
```

Essentially what happens is that it groups the string in to 5 groups:

1. Before the first '|'
2. The first '|'
3. Between the two '|'
4. The second '|'
5. The rest

After the grouping it is reconstructured but without groups 2 and 4, replacing these with '@'. Pretty sure this can be done in a prettier way but I atleast this works!

EDIT: Made a more generic solution using look arounds, hopefully this will work for you.

```
str.replace(/(?=[^\)\(]*(?:\)|\(\w*\)[^\)\(]*(?:\)|\(\w*\)\s*\))))\|/g, '@');
```

Comment: It is useful but not for every dynamic series like that: undefined | gj(fg) ( hjfg(hgj) | hfj(hj) | fjh(hgj) )  | hdfg(hdg) | ghdf(ghdg) | hg(dfh) ( gh(hgdf) | ghdf(hfdg) | hgd(hgf) )  | dfsgf(dsg) | fdg(sdfg) ----- not working for this. I need regex for dynamic series .

Comment: I suspected as much. I will take another look at it.

Comment: Edited my answer with a new regex that should work :)

Comment: If it solved your problem please accept it as an answer

Comment: Its working fine but not for dynamic series: test(zxcZX) ( dsafsdf(sdfSDF) | asdfsd(WRWER) | sadfasd(QWEDQRW) ) | asdfa(89) ( asd(WQWERW) | aftaft(SDFSD) ).

Comment: I need for: a(x) | b(y) | c(3) | d(e) ( x(s) | sd(df) | ds(ds)) | ds(ds) | sd ( sd | dfd(ds) | ds(ds)). replace pipe(|) with @ inside every brackets.